# amCharts json data from mySql - Chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, amcharts

Unable to get a pie chart to display using database data. My json looks good?

Sample Json

`[{"id":1,"sport":"football","score":138.10,"entry":3.00,"winnings":8.00},{"id":2,"sport":"basketball","score":120.00,"entry":10.00,"winnings":20.00}]`

I know the chart is connecting to the dataset, because I get a colored block with NaN as the label, with one block for each row in my database. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLjIO.jpg). "entry" is a float in the Db and I've swapped it with another field that's an Int in the Db, as I was thinking that the float was coming back as Not A Number, but that doesn't look to be the case.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        AmCharts.makeChart("piechartdiv", {
          "type": "pie",
          "dataLoader": {
             "url": "http://siteaddress.com/api/entries",
             "format": "json",
             "showErrors": "true"
          },
         "titlefield": "sport",
         "valuefield": "entry",
         "balloontext": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
   "legend": {
             "align": "center",
             "markertype": "circle"
         }

      });

    </script>

    <div id="piechartwrapper">
        <div id="piechartdiv" style="width: 100%" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields are set up incorrectly - they're case sensitive. `titleField`, `valueField`, `balloonText` and `markerType` are camel-case. Your config has them all in lowercase.

Updated code below:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("piechartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "dataLoader": {
     "url": "http://siteaddress.com/api/entries",
     "format": "json",
     "showErrors": "true"
  },
  "titleField": "sport",
  "valueField": "entry",
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "legend": {
    "align": "center",
    "markerType": "circle"
  }
});
```